# Erro ao importar base de dados do Mnist

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

Boa tarde, estou tentando importar um dataset do mnist mas qdo eu entro com esse código:

```
# importar as bibliotecas necessárias
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

## importar o conjunto de dados MNIST

```
dataset = fetch_mldata("MNIST_Dataset")
(data, labels) = (dataset.data, dataset.target)
```

Aparece a seguinte mensagem informando que a função foi depreciada para a versão 0.2 e removida na 0.22

```
C:\Users\rferr\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\deprecation.py:77: DeprecationWarning: Function fetch_mldata is deprecated; fetch_mldata was deprecated in version 0.20 and will be removed in version 0.22
  warnings.warn(msg, category=DeprecationWarning)
C:\Users\rferr\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\deprecation.py:77: DeprecationWarning: Function mldata_filename is deprecated; mldata_filename was deprecated in version 0.20 and will be removed in version 0.22
  warnings.warn(msg, category=DeprecationWarning)
```

Tentei importar pelo fetch_openml mas não consegui tbm.

O que eu estou fazendo de errado e como eu corrijo isso?

Grato pela atenção.

Comment: Entenda que tudo que e depreciado e "errado", ou seja, existe uma forma melhor de se fazer a mesma coisa que a função faz. Resumindo, funções depreciadas são um aviso que ela será removida em futuras versões, dando margem de tempo para os desenvolvedores adaptarem seus códigos para essa nova forma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baixe o dataset neste [link](https://www.openml.org/d/554) e use isso para abri-lo.

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784')
```